# How to fix "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out" error from .Net 1.1 Framework

Tags: asp.net, webexception

Our `ASP.Net 1.1` WebService application is hosted in `Windows 2003 Server`. 
Another `.Net` Windows Service application is calling the Webservice hosted in the above server every 30 seconds.

We have added a retry call mechanism if any network error happens while calling the web service.

We are occasionally getting the below exception from the Client application while calling the web service:

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

After this error is generated, in the next attempt it will execute with out any error.

On research, I have found that "This could be caused by a stale DNS entry for a proxy or if a request is not received before the socket times out." from the below link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/01/07/you-receive-one-or-more-error-messages-when-you-try-to-make-an-http-request-in-an-application-that-is-built-on-the-net-framework-2-0.aspx

Instead of doing a workaround in the code or in the configuration, how can we find the exact root cause of the problem?

Comment: Best bet is to watch on the wire what is happening with a tool like wireshark.